# Creating shapefile from CSV file with geometry in WKT

Tags: shapefile, polygon, geometry, csv, well-known-text

I would like to get some help creating a polygon shapefile using a CSV (geometry). I have copied the first few rows. I use ArcGIS and a little bit of QGIS. Step by step give will be very helpful, I use a little bit of ArcPy as well.

```
CAR_TYPE_NEW    CARTYPE_DSC AREAHA  ORIG_FID    Shape_Length    Shape_Area  original_row_id RFA NAME    intersection_geometry   intersection_area   relative_fractional_area    geometry
CFP Prescription    2.471338764 1   630.5018018 24713.38764 0   4   WEST    POLYGON ((2209934.442900002 2358876.4274, 2209930.427599996 2358848.2205, 2209929.157499999 2358843.5119, 2209919.724699996 2358820.283199999, 2209918.889899999 2358818.4881, 2209907.606200002 2358797.061799999, 2209900.843699999 2358779.101300001, 2209898.165899999 2358774.200300001, 2209888.310800001 2358760.967599999, 2209883.672700003 2358756.481699999, 2209871.9991 2358748.3785, 2209866.257200003 2358745.625500001, 2209848.8508 2358740.4846, 2209847.486699998 2358740.1336, 2209844.027500004 2358739.682700001, 2209840.543499999 2358739.8398, 2209838.111400001 2358740.3189, 2209822.316 2358744.458000001, 2209821.343900003 2358744.739, 2209818.123899996 2358746.0781, 2209815.184500001 2358747.956599999, 2209813.849299997 2358749.0801, 2209810.883400001 2358751.805599999, 2209808.941600002 2358781.056600001, 2209807.674400002 2358811.043000001, 2209806.408 2358841.029300001, 2209805.141599998 2358871.015700001, 2209775.155500002 2358869.7491, 2209773.924800001 2358898.873100001, 2209773.833099999 2358901.0451, 2209790.093199998 2358926.965700001, 2209791.750200003 2358929.350400001, 2209805.834100001 2358946.768199999, 2209807.895900004 2358948.957800001, 2209810.666199997 2358951.0768, 2209811.696999997 2358951.6895, 2209820.307800002 2358956.4593, 2209822.371699996 2358957.4531, 2209825.700099997 2358958.4965, 2209827.310400002 2358958.783, 2209859.950000003 2358963.1428, 2209861.569300003 2358963.3585, 2209863.407600001 2358963.598299999, 2209866.8917 2358963.441, 2209870.295999996 2358962.6811, 2209874.354699999 2358960.806400001, 2209876.505800001 2358959.5504, 2209894.103399999 2358949.274700001, 2209896.170199998 2358947.8805, 2209898.737899996 2358945.5207, 2209899.453100003 2358944.6941, 2209912.170199998 2358929.1492, 2209925.691 2358912.4976, 2209927.047600001 2358910.612, 2209928.653800003 2358907.516100001, 2209929.711499996 2358904.1272, 2209934.188299999 2358883.488600001, 2209934.624899998 2358880.092, 2209934.442900002 2358876.4274))   24713.38764 1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2209934.442900002 2358876.4274, 2209930.427599996 2358848.2205, 2209929.157499999 2358843.5119, 2209919.724699996 2358820.283199999, 2209918.889899999 2358818.4881, 2209907.606200002 2358797.061799999, 2209900.843699999 2358779.101300001, 2209898.165899999 2358774.200300001, 2209888.310800001 2358760.967599999, 2209883.672700003 2358756.481699999, 2209871.9991 2358748.3785, 2209866.257200003 2358745.625500001, 2209848.8508 2358740.4846, 2209847.486699998 2358740.1336, 2209844.027500004 2358739.682700001, 2209840.543499999 2358739.8398, 2209838.111400001 2358740.3189, 2209822.316 2358744.458000001, 2209821.343900003 2358744.739, 2209818.123899996 2358746.0781, 2209815.184500001 2358747.956599999, 2209813.849299997 2358749.0801, 2209810.883400001 2358751.805599999, 2209808.941600002 2358781.056600001, 2209807.674400002 2358811.043000001, 2209806.408 2358841.029300001, 2209805.141599998 2358871.015700001, 2209775.155500002 2358869.7491, 2209773.924800001 2358898.873100001, 2209773.833099999 2358901.0451, 2209790.093199998 2358926.965700001, 2209791.750200003 2358929.350400001, 2209805.834100001 2358946.768199999, 2209807.895900004 2358948.957800001, 2209810.666199997 2358951.0768, 2209811.696999997 2358951.6895, 2209820.307800002 2358956.4593, 2209822.371699996 2358957.4531, 2209825.700099997 2358958.4965, 2209827.310400002 2358958.783, 2209859.950000003 2358963.1428, 2209861.569300003 2358963.3585, 2209863.407600001 2358963.598299999, 2209866.8917 2358963.441, 2209870.295999996 2358962.6811, 2209874.354699999 2358960.806400001, 2209876.505800001 2358959.5504, 2209894.103399999 2358949.274700001, 2209896.170199998 2358947.8805, 2209898.737899996 2358945.5207, 2209899.453100003 2358944.6941, 2209912.170199998 2358929.1492, 2209925.691 2358912.4976, 2209927.047600001 2358910.612, 2209928.653800003 2358907.516100001, 2209929.711499996 2358904.1272, 2209934.188299999 2358883.488600001, 2209934.624899998 2358880.092, 2209934.442900002 2358876.4274)))
CFP Prescription    1.342618291 1   415.5443447 13426.18291 1   4   WEST    POLYGON ((2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001, 2212291.531900004 2361103.6666, 2212288.047700003 2361103.824000001, 2212283.914899997 2361104.8301, 2212263.986299999 2361111.9987, 2212261.494499996 2361113.091800001, 2212258.555699997 2361114.9703, 2212255.9881 2361117.3299, 2212253.868600003 2361120.099199999, 2212252.717500001 2361122.1754, 2212246.128399998 2361135.9155, 2212244.7575 2361139.7225, 2212240.773100004 2361155.7212, 2212240.322899997 2361159.1796, 2212240.4793 2361162.6644, 2212241.551600002 2361166.9769, 2212246.225699998 2361179.590500001, 2212246.636699997 2361180.6127, 2212252.842600003 2361194.8937, 2212253.458300002 2361196.1829, 2212255.336099997 2361199.1219, 2212257.143399999 2361201.1642, 2212270.000500001 2361213.8244, 2212272.7707 2361215.9443, 2212275.288900003 2361217.301199999, 2212282.5392 2361220.5627, 2212284.152099997 2361221.908599999, 2212287.375200003 2361224.596799999, 2212289.556900002 2361226.265999999, 2212292.652999997 2361227.872400001, 2212296.097099997 2361228.941, 2212299.379900001 2361229.6439, 2212314.753200002 2361232.934, 2212321.471699998 2361233.2159, 2212338.090000004 2361231.096000001, 2212341.494199999 2361230.335900001, 2212344.714599997 2361228.9967, 2212347.653499998 2361227.1182, 2212349.488600001 2361225.519099999, 2212367.040700004 2361208.237300001, 2212367.773900002 2361207.4769, 2212369.892700002 2361204.7064, 2212371.498999998 2361201.610100001, 2212372.6391 2361197.822000001, 2212376.214599997 2361179.548900001, 2212376.373899996 2361172.795400001, 2212373.884800002 2361155.868000001, 2212373.163199998 2361152.7357, 2212371.823799998 2361149.5156, 2212369.945900001 2361146.5766, 2212369.2509 2361145.7225, 2212357.796999998 2361132.4221, 2212355.241599999 2361129.940200001, 2212340.138499998 2361117.686799999, 2212335.438100003 2361114.844799999, 2212318.916500002 2361107.7377, 2212313.4155 2361106.254799999, 2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001))    13426.18291 1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001, 2212291.531900004 2361103.6666, 2212288.047700003 2361103.824000001, 2212283.914899997 2361104.8301, 2212263.986299999 2361111.9987, 2212261.494499996 2361113.091800001, 2212258.555699997 2361114.9703, 2212255.9881 2361117.3299, 2212253.868600003 2361120.099199999, 2212252.717500001 2361122.1754, 2212246.128399998 2361135.9155, 2212244.7575 2361139.7225, 2212240.773100004 2361155.7212, 2212240.322899997 2361159.1796, 2212240.4793 2361162.6644, 2212241.551600002 2361166.9769, 2212246.225699998 2361179.590500001, 2212246.636699997 2361180.6127, 2212252.842600003 2361194.8937, 2212253.458300002 2361196.1829, 2212255.336099997 2361199.1219, 2212257.143399999 2361201.1642, 2212270.000500001 2361213.8244, 2212272.7707 2361215.9443, 2212275.288900003 2361217.301199999, 2212282.5392 2361220.5627, 2212284.152099997 2361221.908599999, 2212287.375200003 2361224.596799999, 2212289.556900002 2361226.265999999, 2212292.652999997 2361227.872400001, 2212296.097099997 2361228.941, 2212299.379900001 2361229.6439, 2212314.753200002 2361232.934, 2212321.471699998 2361233.2159, 2212338.090000004 2361231.096000001, 2212341.494199999 2361230.335900001, 2212344.714599997 2361228.9967, 2212347.653499998 2361227.1182, 2212349.488600001 2361225.519099999, 2212367.040700004 2361208.237300001, 2212367.773900002 2361207.4769, 2212369.892700002 2361204.7064, 2212371.498999998 2361201.610100001, 2212372.6391 2361197.822000001, 2212376.214599997 2361179.548900001, 2212376.373899996 2361172.795400001, 2212373.884800002 2361155.868000001, 2212373.163199998 2361152.7357, 2212371.823799998 2361149.5156, 2212369.945900001 2361146.5766, 2212369.2509 2361145.7225, 2212357.796999998 2361132.4221, 2212355.241599999 2361129.940200001, 2212340.138499998 2361117.686799999, 2212335.438100003 2361114.844799999, 2212318.916500002 2361107.7377, 2212313.4155 2361106.254799999, 2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001)))
CFP Prescription    0.466834504 1   502.6942054 4668.345036 2   4   WEST    POLYGON ((2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001, 2213804.111100003 2362425.339299999, 2213802.369199999 2362425.417399999, 2213800.666599996 2362425.797699999, 2213799.056999996 2362426.4672, 2213797.587200001 2362427.406100001, 2213796.303400002 2362428.5858, 2213795.2434 2362429.971099999, 2213794.440800004 2362431.5189, 2213793.918399997 2362433.1829, 2213793.6932 2362434.9124, 2213793.772200003 2362436.654300001, 2213794.152000003 2362438.356699999, 2213794.884400003 2362440.0858, 2213810.0471 2362468.181299999, 2213822.695100002 2362510.0123, 2213838.838600002 2362573.1228, 2213846.491899997 2362601.163800001, 2213860.585100003 2362651.1065, 2213880.705899999 2362648.737100001, 2213865.759499997 2362595.7718, 2213858.162 2362567.931600001, 2213841.909100004 2362504.4287, 2213828.906900004 2362461.423900001, 2213828.134999998 2362459.567400001, 2213812.492200002 2362430.582699999, 2213811.616700001 2362429.232799999, 2213810.437200002 2362427.949200001, 2213809.052100003 2362426.8891, 2213807.504100002 2362426.086100001, 2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001))    4668.345036 1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001, 2213804.111100003 2362425.339299999, 2213802.369199999 2362425.417399999, 2213800.666599996 2362425.797699999, 2213799.056999996 2362426.4672, 2213797.587200001 2362427.406100001, 2213796.303400002 2362428.5858, 2213795.2434 2362429.971099999, 2213794.440800004 2362431.5189, 2213793.918399997 2362433.1829, 2213793.6932 2362434.9124, 2213793.772200003 2362436.654300001, 2213794.152000003 2362438.356699999, 2213794.884400003 2362440.0858, 2213810.0471 2362468.181299999, 2213822.695100002 2362510.0123, 2213838.838600002 2362573.1228, 2213846.491899997 2362601.163800001, 2213860.585100003 2362651.1065, 2213880.705899999 2362648.737100001, 2213865.759499997 2362595.7718, 2213858.162 2362567.931600001, 2213841.909100004 2362504.4287, 2213828.906900004 2362461.423900001, 2213828.134999998 2362459.567400001, 2213812.492200002 2362430.582699999, 2213811.616700001 2362429.232799999, 2213810.437200002 2362427.949200001, 2213809.052100003 2362426.8891, 2213807.504100002 2362426.086100001, 2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001)))
CFP Prescription    3.156441569 1   1673.373474 31564.41569 3   4   WEST    POLYGON ((2209323.661200002 2364309.9034, 2209281.322300002 2364279.8561, 2209234.243000001 2364247.8882, 2209209.316799998 2364220.3805, 2209199.913900003 2364207.7848, 2209179.937899999 2364181.026000001, 2209178.2892 2364179.0876, 2209139.529100001 2364139.0002, 2209137.451300003 2364137.131999999, 2209102.165700004 2364109.607799999, 2209100.586199999 2364108.493799999, 2209097.4903 2364106.8873, 2209093.689099997 2364105.7456, 2209067.470100001 2364100.633000001, 2209061.946599998 2364100.3347, 2209042.108400002 2364102.043400001, 2209038.704899997 2364102.803100001, 2209035.484200001 2364104.142000001, 2209032.545000002 2364106.020300001, 2209029.435999997 2364108.9978, 2209018.049800001 2364122.535500001, 2209016.472499996 2364124.688099999, 2209014.866599999 2364127.7837, 2209013.822499998 2364131.112, 2209013.357000001 2364135.0704, 2209013.081699997 2364151.079399999, 2209013.429099999 2364155.1523, 2209016.7478 2364172.650199998, 2209017.5189 2364168.268399999, 2209018.431599997 2364164.433899999, 2209019.4934 2364160.450100001, 2209020.6193 2364156.138999999, 2209021.819200002 2364151.592599999, 2209023.102799997 2364146.907499999, 2209024.4793 2364142.178399999, 2209025.958499998 2364137.499200001, 2209027.550999999 2364132.964699998, 2209029.265199997 2364128.670400001, 2209031.111699998 2364124.709399998, 2209033.0995 2364121.179000001, 2209035.238600001 2364118.1723, 2209037.538699999 2364115.7839, 2209040.009000003 2364114.1096, 2209042.659999996 2364113.244100001, 2209045.4802 2364113.122299999, 2209048.419399999 2364113.398899999, 2209051.467600003 2364114.030099999, 2209054.616099998 2364114.988699999, 2209057.856399998 2364116.246800002, 2209061.180100001 2364117.7762, 2209064.579300001 2364119.549899999, 2209068.044 2364121.5396, 2209071.567100003 2364123.7183, 2209075.139399998 2364126.058899999, 2209078.7531 2364128.531500001, 2209082.398900002 2364131.110599998, 2209086.068300001 2364133.767499998, 2209089.753399998 2364136.474800002, 2209093.445900001 2364139.204700001, 2209097.136200003 2364141.9298, 2209100.8169 2364144.621300001, 2209104.479099996 2364147.253800001, 2209108.113700002 2364149.797400001, 2209111.713600002 2364152.225900002, 2209115.2689 2364154.510299999, 2209119.141900003 2364156.838300001, 2209119.990699999 2364157.3686, 2209120.838799998 2364157.8981, 2209121.687600002 2364158.427499998, 2209122.664399996 2364159.455699999, 2209122.5057 2364163.209100001, 2209128.420599997 2364163.596900001, 2209131.8825 2364164.768300001, 2209132.732799999 2364165.295899998, 2209133.5832 2364165.8226, 2209134.432800002 2364166.350299999, 2209135.283200003 2364166.877, 2209136.133500002 2364167.404599998, 2209136.983900003 2364167.931400001, 2209137.835000001 2364168.458099999, 2209138.6853 2364168.985800002, 2209139.535700001 2364169.512499999, 2209140.386 2364170.0392, 2209141.236400001 2364170.565900002, 2209142.0867 2364171.093600001, 2209142.937100001 2364171.620299999, 2209143.7874 2364172.1479, 2209144.637800001 2364172.674699999, 2209145.4881 2364173.202300001, 2209146.337800004 2364173.728999998, 2209147.188100003 2364174.256700002, 2209148.038400002 2364174.784299999, 2209148.887999997 2364175.311900001, 2209149.738399997 2364175.839600001, 2209150.588 2364176.367199998, 2209151.437600002 2364176.8957, 2209152.287100002 2364177.4243, 2209153.136699997 2364177.951900002, 2209153.986299999 2364178.480500001, 2209154.8358 2364179.0099, 2209155.684699997 2364179.5385, 2209156.533500001 2364180.067899998, 2209157.382299997 2364180.5973, 2209158.2311 2364181.126800001, 2209159.079899997 2364181.657200001, 2209160.776000001 2364182.717799999, 2209162.472099997 2364183.7795, 2209164.167300001 2364184.842900001, 2209165.861100003 2364185.907200001, 2209167.554099999 2364186.973299999, 2209169.246299997 2364188.040399998, 2209171.476899996 2364189.132599998, 2209171.463699996 2364189.443300001, 2209171.427100003 2364190.3083, 2209170.371299997 2364215.296399999, 2209169.316200003 2364240.284600001, 2209194.304300003 2364241.340399999, 2209193.249300003 2364266.328600001, 2209168.261100002 2364265.272700001, 2209143.2729 2364264.217700001, 2209118.284599997 2364263.162599999, 2209093.296400003 2364262.1074, 2209068.308200002 2364261.052200001, 2209043.32 2364259.9969, 2209018.331799999 2364258.941500001, 2209003.429300003 2364258.312100001, 2209004.172200002 2364256.097100001, 2209005.441699997 2364252.069600001, 2209006.648900002 2364248.025199998, 2209007.802100003 2364243.978799999, 2209008.910099998 2364239.9494, 2209009.974399999 2364235.980500001, 2209006.535700001 2364239.965700001, 2208988.752599999 2364253.4967, 2208985.342799999 2364256.799699999, 2208971.471000001 2364273.863299999, 2208947.297499999 2364288.544599999, 2208944.917800002 2364290.239700001, 2208931.812700003 2364301.0997, 2208915.2029 2364304.3741, 2208913.5141 2364304.388500001, 2208895.213299997 2364304.5462, 2208881.7152 2364302.2403, 2208870.131700002 2364295.6998, 2208866.8138 2364290.236699998, 2208866.292599998 2364302.587499999, 2208865.237300001 2364327.575599998, 2208864.7271 2364339.6547, 2209328.029299997 2364313.2722, 2209323.661200002 2364309.9034)) 31564.41569 1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2209323.661200002 2364309.9034, 2209281.322300002 2364279.8561, 2209234.243000001 2364247.8882, 2209209.316799998 2364220.3805, 2209199.913900003 2364207.7848, 2209179.937899999 2364181.026000001, 2209178.2892 2364179.0876, 2209139.529100001 2364139.0002, 2209137.451300003 2364137.131999999, 2209102.165700004 2364109.607799999, 2209100.586199999 2364108.493799999, 2209097.4903 2364106.8873, 2209093.689099997 2364105.7456, 2209067.470100001 2364100.633000001, 2209061.946599998 2364100.3347, 2209042.108400002 2364102.043400001, 2209038.704899997 2364102.803100001, 2209035.484200001 2364104.142000001, 2209032.545000002 2364106.020300001, 2209029.435999997 2364108.9978, 2209018.049800001 2364122.535500001, 2209016.472499996 2364124.688099999, 2209014.866599999 2364127.7837, 2209013.822499998 2364131.112, 2209013.357000001 2364135.0704, 2209013.081699997 2364151.079399999, 2209013.429099999 2364155.1523, 2209016.7478 2364172.650199998, 2209017.5189 2364168.268399999, 2209018.431599997 2364164.433899999, 2209019.4934 2364160.450100001, 2209020.6193 2364156.138999999, 2209021.819200002 2364151.592599999, 2209023.102799997 2364146.907499999, 2209024.4793 2364142.178399999, 2209025.958499998 2364137.499200001, 2209027.550999999 2364132.964699998, 2209029.265199997 2364128.670400001, 2209031.111699998 2364124.709399998, 2209033.0995 2364121.179000001, 2209035.238600001 2364118.1723, 2209037.538699999 2364115.7839, 2209040.009000003 2364114.1096, 2209042.659999996 2364113.244100001, 2209045.4802 2364113.122299999, 2209048.419399999 2364113.398899999, 2209051.467600003 2364114.030099999, 2209054.616099998 2364114.988699999, 2209057.856399998 2364116.246800002, 2209061.180100001 2364117.7762, 2209064.579300001 2364119.549899999, 2209068.044 2364121.5396, 2209071.567100003 2364123.7183, 2209075.139399998 2364126.058899999, 2209078.7531 2364128.531500001, 2209082.398900002 2364131.110599998, 2209086.068300001 2364133.767499998, 2209089.753399998 2364136.474800002, 2209093.445900001 2364139.204700001, 2209097.136200003 2364141.9298, 2209100.8169 2364144.621300001, 2209104.479099996 2364147.253800001, 2209108.113700002 2364149.797400001, 2209111.713600002 2364152.225900002, 2209115.2689 2364154.510299999, 2209119.141900003 2364156.838300001, 2209119.990699999 2364157.3686, 2209120.838799998 2364157.8981, 2209121.687600002 2364158.427499998, 2209122.664399996 2364159.455699999, 2209122.5057 2364163.209100001, 2209128.420599997 2364163.596900001, 2209131.8825 2364164.768300001, 2209132.732799999 2364165.295899998, 2209133.5832 2364165.8226, 2209134.432800002 2364166.350299999, 2209135.283200003 2364166.877, 2209136.133500002 2364167.404599998, 2209136.983900003 2364167.931400001, 2209137.835000001 2364168.458099999, 2209138.6853 2364168.985800002, 2209139.535700001 2364169.512499999, 2209140.386 2364170.0392, 2209141.236400001 2364170.565900002, 2209142.0867 2364171.093600001, 2209142.937100001 2364171.620299999, 2209143.7874 2364172.1479, 2209144.637800001 2364172.674699999, 2209145.4881 2364173.202300001, 2209146.337800004 2364173.728999998, 2209147.188100003 2364174.256700002, 2209148.038400002 2364174.784299999, 2209148.887999997 2364175.311900001, 2209149.738399997 2364175.839600001, 2209150.588 2364176.367199998, 2209151.437600002 2364176.8957, 2209152.287100002 2364177.4243, 2209153.136699997 2364177.951900002, 2209153.986299999 2364178.480500001, 2209154.8358 2364179.0099, 2209155.684699997 2364179.5385, 2209156.533500001 2364180.067899998, 2209157.382299997 2364180.5973, 2209158.2311 2364181.126800001, 2209159.079899997 2364181.657200001, 2209160.776000001 2364182.717799999, 2209162.472099997 2364183.7795, 2209164.167300001 2364184.842900001, 2209165.861100003 2364185.907200001, 2209167.554099999 2364186.973299999, 2209169.246299997 2364188.040399998, 2209171.476899996 2364189.132599998, 2209171.463699996 2364189.443300001, 2209171.427100003 2364190.3083, 2209170.371299997 2364215.296399999, 2209169.316200003 2364240.284600001, 2209194.304300003 2364241.340399999, 2209193.249300003 2364266.328600001, 2209168.261100002 2364265.272700001, 2209143.2729 2364264.217700001, 2209118.284599997 2364263.162599999, 2209093.296400003 2364262.1074, 2209068.308200002 2364261.052200001, 2209043.32 2364259.9969, 2209018.331799999 2364258.941500001, 2209003.429300003 2364258.312100001, 2209004.172200002 2364256.097100001, 2209005.441699997 2364252.069600001, 2209006.648900002 2364248.025199998, 2209007.802100003 2364243.978799999, 2209008.910099998 2364239.9494, 2209009.974399999 2364235.980500001, 2209006.535700001 2364239.965700001, 2208988.752599999 2364253.4967, 2208985.342799999 2364256.799699999, 2208971.471000001 2364273.863299999, 2208947.297499999 2364288.544599999, 2208944.917800002 2364290.239700001, 2208931.812700003 2364301.0997, 2208915.2029 2364304.3741, 2208913.5141 2364304.388500001, 2208895.213299997 2364304.5462, 2208881.7152 2364302.2403, 2208870.131700002 2364295.6998, 2208866.8138 2364290.236699998, 2208866.292599998 2364302.587499999, 2208865.237300001 2364327.575599998, 2208864.7271 2364339.6547, 2209328.029299997 2364313.2722, 2209323.661200002 2364309.9034)))
```

Comment: I recommend to be a bit more specific regarding the software that you are willing to use (otherwise your question can be closed as too broad). Also I suggest to share your CSV in a bit more structured manner, keeping spaces and new lines there. Sharing via a cloud could be even more better. Besides, please correct me if I got your wrongly: You want to convert your CSV file into shapefile, do not you? E.g. in QGIS there is a tool for adding a delimited text data (Layer > Add layer > Add delimited Text Layer), where you can specify a Geometry Definition field in WKT format, i.e. `POLYGON ((...`

Comment: What projection system is that geometry in?
Also, that structure seems to be space delimited (triple space?) not comma delimited (CSV).

Answer (score 2):

I estimated with this [tool](http://projfinder.com/) that the EPSG in question was 26851.

The delimiter in your data seemed a little strange, a mix between triple and single spacing. I would suggest, if possible, to export the data with something like a pipe as the delimiter (psv).

In this case I did a string replace to fix all spacing to be triple space. See below.

1. In QGIS we can import from a csv or other types of 'Delimited Text' files via:

   **LAYER > ADD LAYER > ADD DELIMITED TEXT LAYER**
   [image: add delimited text layer]
2. Then, from the interface we specify what kind of delimiter our file has; in this case triple space.

   I specified **triple space** as the **delimiter** by add three blank spaces into
   the regular expression delimiter.
   *(This could easily be | or , depending on what type of file you are importing)*

   We now need to select **Well Known Text (WKT)** and specify which field holds     the geometry, and which projection system/CRS that geometry is in.
   [image: delimited text file import Manager3]
3. Click **ADD** and the data will appear in the map window. This will be a     temporary layer, to make it permanent:
   **RIGHT CLICK > EXPORT > SAVE FEATURES AS**

   [image: Data Mapped]

**Triple spaced version of the data:**

```
CAR_TYPE_NEW   CARTYPE_DSC   AREAHA   ORIG_FID   Shape_Length   Shape_Area   
original_row_id   RFA NAME   intersection_geometry   intersection_area   relative_fractional_area   geometry
CFP Prescription    2.471338764   1   630.5018018   24713.38764   0   4   WEST   POLYGON ((2209934.442900002 2358876.4274, 2209930.427599996 2358848.2205, 2209929.157499999 2358843.5119, 2209919.724699996 2358820.283199999, 2209918.889899999 2358818.4881, 2209907.606200002 2358797.061799999, 2209900.843699999 2358779.101300001, 2209898.165899999 2358774.200300001, 2209888.310800001 2358760.967599999, 2209883.672700003 2358756.481699999, 2209871.9991 2358748.3785, 2209866.257200003 2358745.625500001, 2209848.8508 2358740.4846, 2209847.486699998 2358740.1336, 2209844.027500004 2358739.682700001, 2209840.543499999 2358739.8398, 2209838.111400001 2358740.3189, 2209822.316 2358744.458000001, 2209821.343900003 2358744.739, 2209818.123899996 2358746.0781, 2209815.184500001 2358747.956599999, 2209813.849299997 2358749.0801, 2209810.883400001 2358751.805599999, 2209808.941600002 2358781.056600001, 2209807.674400002 2358811.043000001, 2209806.408 2358841.029300001, 2209805.141599998 2358871.015700001, 2209775.155500002 2358869.7491, 2209773.924800001 2358898.873100001, 2209773.833099999 2358901.0451, 2209790.093199998 2358926.965700001, 2209791.750200003 2358929.350400001, 2209805.834100001 2358946.768199999, 2209807.895900004 2358948.957800001, 2209810.666199997 2358951.0768, 2209811.696999997 2358951.6895, 2209820.307800002 2358956.4593, 2209822.371699996 2358957.4531, 2209825.700099997 2358958.4965, 2209827.310400002 2358958.783, 2209859.950000003 2358963.1428, 2209861.569300003 2358963.3585, 2209863.407600001 2358963.598299999, 2209866.8917 2358963.441, 2209870.295999996 2358962.6811, 2209874.354699999 2358960.806400001, 2209876.505800001 2358959.5504, 2209894.103399999 2358949.274700001, 2209896.170199998 2358947.8805, 2209898.737899996 2358945.5207, 2209899.453100003 2358944.6941, 2209912.170199998 2358929.1492, 2209925.691 2358912.4976, 2209927.047600001 2358910.612, 2209928.653800003 2358907.516100001, 2209929.711499996 2358904.1272, 2209934.188299999 2358883.488600001, 2209934.624899998 2358880.092, 2209934.442900002 2358876.4274))   24713.38764   1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2209934.442900002 2358876.4274, 2209930.427599996 2358848.2205, 2209929.157499999 2358843.5119, 2209919.724699996 2358820.283199999, 2209918.889899999 2358818.4881, 2209907.606200002 2358797.061799999, 2209900.843699999 2358779.101300001, 2209898.165899999 2358774.200300001, 2209888.310800001 2358760.967599999, 2209883.672700003 2358756.481699999, 2209871.9991 2358748.3785, 2209866.257200003 2358745.625500001, 2209848.8508 2358740.4846, 2209847.486699998 2358740.1336, 2209844.027500004 2358739.682700001, 2209840.543499999 2358739.8398, 2209838.111400001 2358740.3189, 2209822.316 2358744.458000001, 2209821.343900003 2358744.739, 2209818.123899996 2358746.0781, 2209815.184500001 2358747.956599999, 2209813.849299997 2358749.0801, 2209810.883400001 2358751.805599999, 2209808.941600002 2358781.056600001, 2209807.674400002 2358811.043000001, 2209806.408 2358841.029300001, 2209805.141599998 2358871.015700001, 2209775.155500002 2358869.7491, 2209773.924800001 2358898.873100001, 2209773.833099999 2358901.0451, 2209790.093199998 2358926.965700001, 2209791.750200003 2358929.350400001, 2209805.834100001 2358946.768199999, 2209807.895900004 2358948.957800001, 2209810.666199997 2358951.0768, 2209811.696999997 2358951.6895, 2209820.307800002 2358956.4593, 2209822.371699996 2358957.4531, 2209825.700099997 2358958.4965, 2209827.310400002 2358958.783, 2209859.950000003 2358963.1428, 2209861.569300003 2358963.3585, 2209863.407600001 2358963.598299999, 2209866.8917 2358963.441, 2209870.295999996 2358962.6811, 2209874.354699999 2358960.806400001, 2209876.505800001 2358959.5504, 2209894.103399999 2358949.274700001, 2209896.170199998 2358947.8805, 2209898.737899996 2358945.5207, 2209899.453100003 2358944.6941, 2209912.170199998 2358929.1492, 2209925.691 2358912.4976, 2209927.047600001 2358910.612, 2209928.653800003 2358907.516100001, 2209929.711499996 2358904.1272, 2209934.188299999 2358883.488600001, 2209934.624899998 2358880.092, 2209934.442900002 2358876.4274)))
CFP Prescription   1.342618291   1   415.5443447   13426.18291   1   4   WEST   POLYGON ((2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001, 2212291.531900004 2361103.6666, 2212288.047700003 2361103.824000001, 2212283.914899997 2361104.8301, 2212263.986299999 2361111.9987, 2212261.494499996 2361113.091800001, 2212258.555699997 2361114.9703, 2212255.9881 2361117.3299, 2212253.868600003 2361120.099199999, 2212252.717500001 2361122.1754, 2212246.128399998 2361135.9155, 2212244.7575 2361139.7225, 2212240.773100004 2361155.7212, 2212240.322899997 2361159.1796, 2212240.4793 2361162.6644, 2212241.551600002 2361166.9769, 2212246.225699998 2361179.590500001, 2212246.636699997 2361180.6127, 2212252.842600003 2361194.8937, 2212253.458300002 2361196.1829, 2212255.336099997 2361199.1219, 2212257.143399999 2361201.1642, 2212270.000500001 2361213.8244, 2212272.7707 2361215.9443, 2212275.288900003 2361217.301199999, 2212282.5392 2361220.5627, 2212284.152099997 2361221.908599999, 2212287.375200003 2361224.596799999, 2212289.556900002 2361226.265999999, 2212292.652999997 2361227.872400001, 2212296.097099997 2361228.941, 2212299.379900001 2361229.6439, 2212314.753200002 2361232.934, 2212321.471699998 2361233.2159, 2212338.090000004 2361231.096000001, 2212341.494199999 2361230.335900001, 2212344.714599997 2361228.9967, 2212347.653499998 2361227.1182, 2212349.488600001 2361225.519099999, 2212367.040700004 2361208.237300001, 2212367.773900002 2361207.4769, 2212369.892700002 2361204.7064, 2212371.498999998 2361201.610100001, 2212372.6391 2361197.822000001, 2212376.214599997 2361179.548900001, 2212376.373899996 2361172.795400001, 2212373.884800002 2361155.868000001, 2212373.163199998 2361152.7357, 2212371.823799998 2361149.5156, 2212369.945900001 2361146.5766, 2212369.2509 2361145.7225, 2212357.796999998 2361132.4221, 2212355.241599999 2361129.940200001, 2212340.138499998 2361117.686799999, 2212335.438100003 2361114.844799999, 2212318.916500002 2361107.7377, 2212313.4155 2361106.254799999, 2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001))   13426.18291   1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001, 2212291.531900004 2361103.6666, 2212288.047700003 2361103.824000001, 2212283.914899997 2361104.8301, 2212263.986299999 2361111.9987, 2212261.494499996 2361113.091800001, 2212258.555699997 2361114.9703, 2212255.9881 2361117.3299, 2212253.868600003 2361120.099199999, 2212252.717500001 2361122.1754, 2212246.128399998 2361135.9155, 2212244.7575 2361139.7225, 2212240.773100004 2361155.7212, 2212240.322899997 2361159.1796, 2212240.4793 2361162.6644, 2212241.551600002 2361166.9769, 2212246.225699998 2361179.590500001, 2212246.636699997 2361180.6127, 2212252.842600003 2361194.8937, 2212253.458300002 2361196.1829, 2212255.336099997 2361199.1219, 2212257.143399999 2361201.1642, 2212270.000500001 2361213.8244, 2212272.7707 2361215.9443, 2212275.288900003 2361217.301199999, 2212282.5392 2361220.5627, 2212284.152099997 2361221.908599999, 2212287.375200003 2361224.596799999, 2212289.556900002 2361226.265999999, 2212292.652999997 2361227.872400001, 2212296.097099997 2361228.941, 2212299.379900001 2361229.6439, 2212314.753200002 2361232.934, 2212321.471699998 2361233.2159, 2212338.090000004 2361231.096000001, 2212341.494199999 2361230.335900001, 2212344.714599997 2361228.9967, 2212347.653499998 2361227.1182, 2212349.488600001 2361225.519099999, 2212367.040700004 2361208.237300001, 2212367.773900002 2361207.4769, 2212369.892700002 2361204.7064, 2212371.498999998 2361201.610100001, 2212372.6391 2361197.822000001, 2212376.214599997 2361179.548900001, 2212376.373899996 2361172.795400001, 2212373.884800002 2361155.868000001, 2212373.163199998 2361152.7357, 2212371.823799998 2361149.5156, 2212369.945900001 2361146.5766, 2212369.2509 2361145.7225, 2212357.796999998 2361132.4221, 2212355.241599999 2361129.940200001, 2212340.138499998 2361117.686799999, 2212335.438100003 2361114.844799999, 2212318.916500002 2361107.7377, 2212313.4155 2361106.254799999, 2212293.092600003 2361103.794500001)))
CFP Prescription   0.466834504   1   502.6942054   4668.345036   2   4   WEST   POLYGON ((2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001, 2213804.111100003 2362425.339299999, 2213802.369199999 2362425.417399999, 2213800.666599996 2362425.797699999, 2213799.056999996 2362426.4672, 2213797.587200001 2362427.406100001, 2213796.303400002 2362428.5858, 2213795.2434 2362429.971099999, 2213794.440800004 2362431.5189, 2213793.918399997 2362433.1829, 2213793.6932 2362434.9124, 2213793.772200003 2362436.654300001, 2213794.152000003 2362438.356699999, 2213794.884400003 2362440.0858, 2213810.0471 2362468.181299999, 2213822.695100002 2362510.0123, 2213838.838600002 2362573.1228, 2213846.491899997 2362601.163800001, 2213860.585100003 2362651.1065, 2213880.705899999 2362648.737100001, 2213865.759499997 2362595.7718, 2213858.162 2362567.931600001, 2213841.909100004 2362504.4287, 2213828.906900004 2362461.423900001, 2213828.134999998 2362459.567400001, 2213812.492200002 2362430.582699999, 2213811.616700001 2362429.232799999, 2213810.437200002 2362427.949200001, 2213809.052100003 2362426.8891, 2213807.504100002 2362426.086100001, 2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001))   4668.345036   1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001, 2213804.111100003 2362425.339299999, 2213802.369199999 2362425.417399999, 2213800.666599996 2362425.797699999, 2213799.056999996 2362426.4672, 2213797.587200001 2362427.406100001, 2213796.303400002 2362428.5858, 2213795.2434 2362429.971099999, 2213794.440800004 2362431.5189, 2213793.918399997 2362433.1829, 2213793.6932 2362434.9124, 2213793.772200003 2362436.654300001, 2213794.152000003 2362438.356699999, 2213794.884400003 2362440.0858, 2213810.0471 2362468.181299999, 2213822.695100002 2362510.0123, 2213838.838600002 2362573.1228, 2213846.491899997 2362601.163800001, 2213860.585100003 2362651.1065, 2213880.705899999 2362648.737100001, 2213865.759499997 2362595.7718, 2213858.162 2362567.931600001, 2213841.909100004 2362504.4287, 2213828.906900004 2362461.423900001, 2213828.134999998 2362459.567400001, 2213812.492200002 2362430.582699999, 2213811.616700001 2362429.232799999, 2213810.437200002 2362427.949200001, 2213809.052100003 2362426.8891, 2213807.504100002 2362426.086100001, 2213805.840499997 2362425.564300001)))
CFP Prescription   3.156441569   1   1673.373474   31564.41569   3   4   WEST   POLYGON ((2209323.661200002 2364309.9034, 2209281.322300002 2364279.8561, 2209234.243000001 2364247.8882, 2209209.316799998 2364220.3805, 2209199.913900003 2364207.7848, 2209179.937899999 2364181.026000001, 2209178.2892 2364179.0876, 2209139.529100001 2364139.0002, 2209137.451300003 2364137.131999999, 2209102.165700004 2364109.607799999, 2209100.586199999 2364108.493799999, 2209097.4903 2364106.8873, 2209093.689099997 2364105.7456, 2209067.470100001 2364100.633000001, 2209061.946599998 2364100.3347, 2209042.108400002 2364102.043400001, 2209038.704899997 2364102.803100001, 2209035.484200001 2364104.142000001, 2209032.545000002 2364106.020300001, 2209029.435999997 2364108.9978, 2209018.049800001 2364122.535500001, 2209016.472499996 2364124.688099999, 2209014.866599999 2364127.7837, 2209013.822499998 2364131.112, 2209013.357000001 2364135.0704, 2209013.081699997 2364151.079399999, 2209013.429099999 2364155.1523, 2209016.7478 2364172.650199998, 2209017.5189 2364168.268399999, 2209018.431599997 2364164.433899999, 2209019.4934 2364160.450100001, 2209020.6193 2364156.138999999, 2209021.819200002 2364151.592599999, 2209023.102799997 2364146.907499999, 2209024.4793 2364142.178399999, 2209025.958499998 2364137.499200001, 2209027.550999999 2364132.964699998, 2209029.265199997 2364128.670400001, 2209031.111699998 2364124.709399998, 2209033.0995 2364121.179000001, 2209035.238600001 2364118.1723, 2209037.538699999 2364115.7839, 2209040.009000003 2364114.1096, 2209042.659999996 2364113.244100001, 2209045.4802 2364113.122299999, 2209048.419399999 2364113.398899999, 2209051.467600003 2364114.030099999, 2209054.616099998 2364114.988699999, 2209057.856399998 2364116.246800002, 2209061.180100001 2364117.7762, 2209064.579300001 2364119.549899999, 2209068.044 2364121.5396, 2209071.567100003 2364123.7183, 2209075.139399998 2364126.058899999, 2209078.7531 2364128.531500001, 2209082.398900002 2364131.110599998, 2209086.068300001 2364133.767499998, 2209089.753399998 2364136.474800002, 2209093.445900001 2364139.204700001, 2209097.136200003 2364141.9298, 2209100.8169 2364144.621300001, 2209104.479099996 2364147.253800001, 2209108.113700002 2364149.797400001, 2209111.713600002 2364152.225900002, 2209115.2689 2364154.510299999, 2209119.141900003 2364156.838300001, 2209119.990699999 2364157.3686, 2209120.838799998 2364157.8981, 2209121.687600002 2364158.427499998, 2209122.664399996 2364159.455699999, 2209122.5057 2364163.209100001, 2209128.420599997 2364163.596900001, 2209131.8825 2364164.768300001, 2209132.732799999 2364165.295899998, 2209133.5832 2364165.8226, 2209134.432800002 2364166.350299999, 2209135.283200003 2364166.877, 2209136.133500002 2364167.404599998, 2209136.983900003 2364167.931400001, 2209137.835000001 2364168.458099999, 2209138.6853 2364168.985800002, 2209139.535700001 2364169.512499999, 2209140.386 2364170.0392, 2209141.236400001 2364170.565900002, 2209142.0867 2364171.093600001, 2209142.937100001 2364171.620299999, 2209143.7874 2364172.1479, 2209144.637800001 2364172.674699999, 2209145.4881 2364173.202300001, 2209146.337800004 2364173.728999998, 2209147.188100003 2364174.256700002, 2209148.038400002 2364174.784299999, 2209148.887999997 2364175.311900001, 2209149.738399997 2364175.839600001, 2209150.588 2364176.367199998, 2209151.437600002 2364176.8957, 2209152.287100002 2364177.4243, 2209153.136699997 2364177.951900002, 2209153.986299999 2364178.480500001, 2209154.8358 2364179.0099, 2209155.684699997 2364179.5385, 2209156.533500001 2364180.067899998, 2209157.382299997 2364180.5973, 2209158.2311 2364181.126800001, 2209159.079899997 2364181.657200001, 2209160.776000001 2364182.717799999, 2209162.472099997 2364183.7795, 2209164.167300001 2364184.842900001, 2209165.861100003 2364185.907200001, 2209167.554099999 2364186.973299999, 2209169.246299997 2364188.040399998, 2209171.476899996 2364189.132599998, 2209171.463699996 2364189.443300001, 2209171.427100003 2364190.3083, 2209170.371299997 2364215.296399999, 2209169.316200003 2364240.284600001, 2209194.304300003 2364241.340399999, 2209193.249300003 2364266.328600001, 2209168.261100002 2364265.272700001, 2209143.2729 2364264.217700001, 2209118.284599997 2364263.162599999, 2209093.296400003 2364262.1074, 2209068.308200002 2364261.052200001, 2209043.32 2364259.9969, 2209018.331799999 2364258.941500001, 2209003.429300003 2364258.312100001, 2209004.172200002 2364256.097100001, 2209005.441699997 2364252.069600001, 2209006.648900002 2364248.025199998, 2209007.802100003 2364243.978799999, 2209008.910099998 2364239.9494, 2209009.974399999 2364235.980500001, 2209006.535700001 2364239.965700001, 2208988.752599999 2364253.4967, 2208985.342799999 2364256.799699999, 2208971.471000001 2364273.863299999, 2208947.297499999 2364288.544599999, 2208944.917800002 2364290.239700001, 2208931.812700003 2364301.0997, 2208915.2029 2364304.3741, 2208913.5141 2364304.388500001, 2208895.213299997 2364304.5462, 2208881.7152 2364302.2403, 2208870.131700002 2364295.6998, 2208866.8138 2364290.236699998, 2208866.292599998 2364302.587499999, 2208865.237300001 2364327.575599998, 2208864.7271 2364339.6547, 2209328.029299997 2364313.2722, 2209323.661200002 2364309.9034))   31564.41569   1   MULTIPOLYGON (((2209323.661200002 2364309.9034, 2209281.322300002 2364279.8561, 2209234.243000001 2364247.8882, 2209209.316799998 2364220.3805, 2209199.913900003 2364207.7848, 2209179.937899999 2364181.026000001, 2209178.2892 2364179.0876, 2209139.529100001 2364139.0002, 2209137.451300003 2364137.131999999, 2209102.165700004 2364109.607799999, 2209100.586199999 2364108.493799999, 2209097.4903 2364106.8873, 2209093.689099997 2364105.7456, 2209067.470100001 2364100.633000001, 2209061.946599998 2364100.3347, 2209042.108400002 2364102.043400001, 2209038.704899997 2364102.803100001, 2209035.484200001 2364104.142000001, 2209032.545000002 2364106.020300001, 2209029.435999997 2364108.9978, 2209018.049800001 2364122.535500001, 2209016.472499996 2364124.688099999, 2209014.866599999 2364127.7837, 2209013.822499998 2364131.112, 2209013.357000001 2364135.0704, 2209013.081699997 2364151.079399999, 2209013.429099999 2364155.1523, 2209016.7478 2364172.650199998, 2209017.5189 2364168.268399999, 2209018.431599997 2364164.433899999, 2209019.4934 2364160.450100001, 2209020.6193 2364156.138999999, 2209021.819200002 2364151.592599999, 2209023.102799997 2364146.907499999, 2209024.4793 2364142.178399999, 2209025.958499998 2364137.499200001, 2209027.550999999 2364132.964699998, 2209029.265199997 2364128.670400001, 2209031.111699998 2364124.709399998, 2209033.0995 2364121.179000001, 2209035.238600001 2364118.1723, 2209037.538699999 2364115.7839, 2209040.009000003 2364114.1096, 2209042.659999996 2364113.244100001, 2209045.4802 2364113.122299999, 2209048.419399999 2364113.398899999, 2209051.467600003 2364114.030099999, 2209054.616099998 2364114.988699999, 2209057.856399998 2364116.246800002, 2209061.180100001 2364117.7762, 2209064.579300001 2364119.549899999, 2209068.044 2364121.5396, 2209071.567100003 2364123.7183, 2209075.139399998 2364126.058899999, 2209078.7531 2364128.531500001, 2209082.398900002 2364131.110599998, 2209086.068300001 2364133.767499998, 2209089.753399998 2364136.474800002, 2209093.445900001 2364139.204700001, 2209097.136200003 2364141.9298, 2209100.8169 2364144.621300001, 2209104.479099996 2364147.253800001, 2209108.113700002 2364149.797400001, 2209111.713600002 2364152.225900002, 2209115.2689 2364154.510299999, 2209119.141900003 2364156.838300001, 2209119.990699999 2364157.3686, 2209120.838799998 2364157.8981, 2209121.687600002 2364158.427499998, 2209122.664399996 2364159.455699999, 2209122.5057 2364163.209100001, 2209128.420599997 2364163.596900001, 2209131.8825 2364164.768300001, 2209132.732799999 2364165.295899998, 2209133.5832 2364165.8226, 2209134.432800002 2364166.350299999, 2209135.283200003 2364166.877, 2209136.133500002 2364167.404599998, 2209136.983900003 2364167.931400001, 2209137.835000001 2364168.458099999, 2209138.6853 2364168.985800002, 2209139.535700001 2364169.512499999, 2209140.386 2364170.0392, 2209141.236400001 2364170.565900002, 2209142.0867 2364171.093600001, 2209142.937100001 2364171.620299999, 2209143.7874 2364172.1479, 2209144.637800001 2364172.674699999, 2209145.4881 2364173.202300001, 2209146.337800004 2364173.728999998, 2209147.188100003 2364174.256700002, 2209148.038400002 2364174.784299999, 2209148.887999997 2364175.311900001, 2209149.738399997 2364175.839600001, 2209150.588 2364176.367199998, 2209151.437600002 2364176.8957, 2209152.287100002 2364177.4243, 2209153.136699997 2364177.951900002, 2209153.986299999 2364178.480500001, 2209154.8358 2364179.0099, 2209155.684699997 2364179.5385, 2209156.533500001 2364180.067899998, 2209157.382299997 2364180.5973, 2209158.2311 2364181.126800001, 2209159.079899997 2364181.657200001, 2209160.776000001 2364182.717799999, 2209162.472099997 2364183.7795, 2209164.167300001 2364184.842900001, 2209165.861100003 2364185.907200001, 2209167.554099999 2364186.973299999, 2209169.246299997 2364188.040399998, 2209171.476899996 2364189.132599998, 2209171.463699996 2364189.443300001, 2209171.427100003 2364190.3083, 2209170.371299997 2364215.296399999, 2209169.316200003 2364240.284600001, 2209194.304300003 2364241.340399999, 2209193.249300003 2364266.328600001, 2209168.261100002 2364265.272700001, 2209143.2729 2364264.217700001, 2209118.284599997 2364263.162599999, 2209093.296400003 2364262.1074, 2209068.308200002 2364261.052200001, 2209043.32 2364259.9969, 2209018.331799999 2364258.941500001, 2209003.429300003 2364258.312100001, 2209004.172200002 2364256.097100001, 2209005.441699997 2364252.069600001, 2209006.648900002 2364248.025199998, 2209007.802100003 2364243.978799999, 2209008.910099998 2364239.9494, 2209009.974399999 2364235.980500001, 2209006.535700001 2364239.965700001, 2208988.752599999 2364253.4967, 2208985.342799999 2364256.799699999, 2208971.471000001 2364273.863299999, 2208947.297499999 2364288.544599999, 2208944.917800002 2364290.239700001, 2208931.812700003 2364301.0997, 2208915.2029 2364304.3741, 2208913.5141 2364304.388500001, 2208895.213299997 2364304.5462, 2208881.7152 2364302.2403, 2208870.131700002 2364295.6998, 2208866.8138 2364290.236699998, 2208866.292599998 2364302.587499999, 2208865.237300001 2364327.575599998, 2208864.7271 2364339.6547, 2209328.029299997 2364313.2722, 2209323.661200002 2364309.9034)))
```