# Convert geometry present in pgAdmin to shapefile

Tags: shapefile

I have a Table in pgAdmin which has geometry column as `0102000000020003C6FBF73A4F353C0CD27FDFC49CC41404ACF16C4A3F353C053EC34AD57CC4140` I have downloaded the file as CSV.

I want to convert this into a shapefile. How can I do it using Python (I can do it using Shapely, GeoPandas, fiona, OGR) or QGIS ? I can't use PostGIS command line as well

Comment: shapely and geopandas use ogr which is the preferred solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Run this query in pgAdmin:

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(you_geometry_column) as geometry FROM your_schema."your_table"
```

2- Export the result to .csv file

3- Use [Creating shapefile from CSV file with geometry in WKT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403998/creating-shapefile-from-csv-file-with-geometry-in-wkt) to convert it to a shapefile.

Answer (score 1):

Add the table/query to QGIS as layer (either via datasource manager or via db manager) then right click the layer, choose save as and select your file format.

Comment: I am not using PostGIS, I am using PgAdmin

Comment: Pgadmin is a client talking to postgis

Answer (score 1):

With [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr):

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp PG:dbname="my_database" "my_table"`

see [here](https://jakobmiksch.eu/post/gdal_ogr/#postgis) for details.